# PHP pg_connect slow time with Docker

Tags: php, postgresql, docker

I'm running with Docker and I would like setting up a PostgreSQL database container with an Apache (with PHP) container. But, when I'm trying to connect PHP with PostgreSQL by link, I've got an average of 109ms only for the `pg_connect` function. If I made the same operation on my host system, I obtain only 4ms for the same connection.

I tried debug the DNS resolver but it responds in `min/avg/max = 0.074/0.113/0.130 ms`. I also disabled the SSL connection from PostgreSQL. I turned on the log connection and this is the output (tested with two connections) :

```sh
2016-04-05 14:07:32.395 CESTLOG:  connexion reçue : hôte=172.18.0.7 port=48924
2016-04-05 14:07:32.396 CESTLOG:  connexion autorisée : utilisateur=postgres
2016-04-05 14:07:32.441 CESTLOG:  connexion reçue : hôte=172.18.0.7 port=48926
2016-04-05 14:07:32.442 CESTLOG:  connexion autorisée : utilisateur=postgres
```

As you can see, I've got 45ms between the first connection and the second and each connection itself take an average of 20ms.

So if I resumed the situation :

- DNS Resolver time (~ 0.113ms)
- Connection average time (~ 20ms)
- Time between two connections (~ 45ms)

I have the problem in Docker but no in the host machine (PHP can communicate with PSQL with port association with Docker port forward). Where could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I don't know how... I dropped some applications like BlackFire, etc. and the problem has disappear.